# How do I pass a "const_reverse_iterator" parameter to "std::vector::erase()"?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

`std::vector::erase()` does not accept reverse iterator.
Is there any way to call this method with a reverse iterator?

My sample code is:

```
std::vector<int> MyVector;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    MyVector.push_back(i);
}
// Now suppose that I want to erase the last three elements
int nEraseCount = 0;
for (std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it=MyVector.rbegin();
        it<MyVector.rend(); ++it)
{
    MyVector.erase(it);
    if (++nEraseCount == 3) break;
}
```

However, this sample code is not working, because `it` is a reverse iterator and `erase()` does not take reverse iterator as its argument.

How do I modify this code so that it works?

Comment: Even if the iterators were compatible, erase will invalidate them and cause your iteration to fail. Better employ the remove-erase idiom!

Comment: Is your code a simplified example where you need reverse iterator or are you trying to remove the last three elements from a vector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert from reverse_iterators to iterators using base() although you need to subtract one to get the one that points to the same element thus rbegin() points to end() and rend() points to begin() (because it is not possible to point to one before the beginning in reality).

You have more of a problem because you are using a const_reverse_iterator which cannot be converted to a non-const one and erase requires non-const iterators. The logic is that you are modifying the collection so you use a non-const iterator.

In your case, you have a bigger problem with your loop as you are removing iterators thus invalidating them, then trying to move back to the previous element.

If you need to remove the last 3 elements then you should use an erase method that takes a range rather than remove them one at a time.

This can be done using `MyVector.erase(MyVector.rbegin() + 3).base(), MyVector.end() )` in this particular case as long as you know that `MyVector.size() >= 3`

Comment: What should I write instead of "MyVector.erase(it);" in my code?

Comment: If you removing a range then get the whole range then call the version of erase that takes 2 iterators. If you are removing based on a predicate use the erase/remove_if idiom

Answer (score 5):

I would workaround the problem by not using a reverse iterator. I'll probably write something like that:

```
std::vector<int> MyVector;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    MyVector.push_back(i);
}
// Now suppose that I want to erase the last three elements
int nEraseCount = 0;
while (nEraseCount < 3 && !MyVector.empty())
{
    MyVector.pop_back();
    ++nEraseCount;
}
```

Comment: Erm, why? `resize()` is all you need if you are trimming!

Comment: I supposed he had to do some work with the item before removing them. If this is not the case, `resize()` is effectively a more indicated solution.

Answer (score 4):

Okay you have several options - you are erasing from the end - so you could:

`resize()`

```
if (MyVector.size() > 3)
  MyVector.resize(MyVector.size() - 3);
else
  MyVector.clear(); // presumably you don't want all anyway!
```

simple difference

```
if (MyVector.size() > 3)
  MyVector.erase(MyVector.end() - 3, MyVector.end());
else
  MyVector.clear(); // presumably you don't want all anyway!
```

The approach you've taken is not very idiomatic

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove N elements at the back:

```
size_t N = 3;
size_t to_remove = std::min(vec.size(), N);
vec.erase(vec.end() - to_remove, vec.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass `const_iterator` or `const_reverse_iterator` to `erase()`, as it is **readonly** iterator!

You should use non-const *forward* iterator version : `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: @Downvoter : please specify the reason. At least let me know where I'm wrong!

Comment: `erase` requires `iterator` argument(s), not `const_iterator` - so almost all of your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Joe : I posted the function signature also. Please see that. It will work with BOTH!

Comment: It takes iterator in C++98 and C++03 - it will take const_iterator in C++0x.

Comment: @Nawaz, unless it's your compiler specific, `erase()` expects a non `const_iterator`. You'll get a compile error if you try to pass in a `const_iterator` into erase. See this: http://ideone.com/Xev5w

Comment: @Joe : I'm using MSVC++08, which is C++03.

Comment: @Nim : That makes sense. :-) In fact, that is what I expected when I first wrote my answer. But when I say MSVC++03 implementation, I changed that. Let me rollback my answer. :D

Comment: It's still wrong, `erase` takes `iterator` only, not `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: @Joe : Yeah, I edited that portion of my answer. You're too quick to reply. :)